# How to find element in appium using text?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, appium

I want to click on a button on a website. Is there a code which can allow me to click on the element by using the TEXT field? I can neither use the resource id field nor name as they are empty. I tried to click on the element using the xpath but that did not work.

Comment: which device OS, Android or iOS?

Comment: @Vault23 It is an Android Device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is example using Java, but i believe that it is pretty easy to migrate it to a Python.
You need to use **AndroidUiAutomator**:

```
androidDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"your_text\")").click();
```

Comment: Tried this solution but it says " Search did not succeed===  'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_android_uiautomator' "

Comment: this is not attribute, this is a method. paste your code for search here

Comment: self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Submit")')

Comment: have you tried this one? `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Submit')]")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working. Had tried using absolute and relative xpath but not like this. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. you can check this answer as acceptable.